# I want to get keyword with keyword() funtion to search google image. How should i fix it

Tags: python, selenium, user-interface, tkinter

> import os
> import tkinter.ttk as ttk import tkinter.messagebox as msgbox from
> tkinter import
> from tkinter import filedialog
> from PIL import Image
> root = Tk() root.title("Nado GUI")
>
> def keyword():
> keyword.get()
> keyword.delete(0, END)
>
> def google_image():
>
> ```
> from selenium import webdriver
> from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
> import time
> import urllib.request
>
> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
> driver.get("https://www.google.co.kr/imghp?hl=ko&tab=wi&authuser=0&ogbl")
> elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
>    
> elem.send_keys(keyword())
> elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
>
> images = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".rg_i.Q4LuWd")
> count = 0
> for image in images:
>     try:
>         image.click()
>         time.sleep(2)
>         imgUrl = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/c-wiz/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/c-wiz/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/a/img').get_attribute("src")
>         opener=urllib.request.build_opener()
>         opener.addheaders=[('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1941.0 Safari/537.36')]
>         urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
>         urllib.request.urlretrieve(imgUrl, keyword + str(count) + ".jpg")
>         count = count + 1
>         if count >= 6:
>             break
>     except:
>         pass
>
> driver.close()
> ```

> file_frame = Frame(root) file_frame.pack(fill="x", padx=5, pady=5)>
>
> btn_keyword = Button(file_frame, text= "Click", command=keyword)
> btn_keyword.pack(side="right", padx=5, pady=5) keyword =
> Entry(file_frame, width=30) keyword.pack(side="right", padx=5, pady=5)
>
> frame_run = Frame(root) frame_run.pack(fill="x", padx=5, pady=5)
>
> btn_close = Button(frame_run, padx=5, pady=5, text="Close", width=12, command=root.quit)
> btn_close.pack(side="right", padx=5, pady=5)
>
> btn_start = Button(frame_run, padx=5, pady=5, text="Start", width=12, command=google_image)
> btn_start.pack(side="right", padx=5, pady=5)
>
> root.resizable(False, False)
>
> root.mainloop()

Comment: edit question and use function for `Code Sample` (button with `{}`) instead of `Blockquote`.

Comment: describe problem in question's body, not in title

Comment: don't use the same name `keyword` for function's name `def keyword(...)` and for other variable `keyword = Entry(...)` better use `def get_keyword(): return keyword.get()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your main problem is that you use the same name `keyword` for function and widget.

You should use different names ie.

```
keyword_entry = Entry(...)
```

and then

```
def keyword():
    value = keyword_entry.get()
    keyword_entry.delete(0, END)
    return value
```

And then you can use it

```
elem.send_keys(keyword())
```